# call C library function from Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, bridging-header

The bridging header file says,

```
#define qnorm5        Rf_qnorm5
#define qnorm qnorm5

double  qnorm5(double, double, double, int, int);
```

and the code (which compiles!) says

```
let myresult = qnorm (0.75,0,1,1,0)
```

but the linker complains

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_qnorm", referenced from:
      macOS_app_test.ViewController.sayButtonClicked(Any) -> () in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From the output, the correct library is found and linked, but the linker does not look for the correct symbol. The symbol the linker should look for, is  `_Rf_qnorm5`.

Comment: you added path on "Library Search Paths"?

Comment: `let myresult = qnorm (0.75,0,1,1,0)` should not compile (and does not in my test).

Comment: The linker says

`… -L/usr/local/src/R-3.5.1/src/nmath …`

so I assume so. And yes, it's there.

I don't think the problem is that the library isn't found. I think the problem is that the right symbol isn't searched for.

Comment: I had same problem (undefined for arm64) and I solve adding the path, and yes, I had added the .a libraries

Comment: Martin R, have you included the proper bridging header files?

Comment: Augusto, where did you place the bridging header files?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I ought to have understood that the proper function name should be `Rf_qnorm5`.

Also, there was a problem with XCode actually finding the bridging header file. With both in place, the code works.